# Does the Replace Windows X with Ubuntu option in the installation setup replace a single partition or the whole drive

Tags: partitioning, ubiquity

In the Ubuntu installation, when the user gets to the part about selecting which method to use to install Ubuntu, the user will find several options like the ones shown below:

[image]

If the user already has Windows on the computer, will selecting "Replace Windows X with Ubuntu" modify the partition where Windows is installed or will it format the whole drive.

There are several doubts regarding this, from other letters (As in Windows D:, E:...) deleted because they were in the same physical drive to not reading the other partitions because of the same reason.

Comment: My assumption would be "format the entire drive". Why would you keep your Windows drive(s) after you've replaced Windows? What would read them? I suggest "something else" if you have *doubts*.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You are missing the point. The question is in regards to formatting 1 partition versus a whole drive. The case applies for users with only one physical drive but they only want to replace C: (where windows is typically found) and leave D:, E:.. untouched since they normally are the backup.

Comment: I may well be missing the point, but if D and E are partitions (e.g. on the same drive) then "format the entire drive" will delete them. D: and E: are normally the backup according to whom?

Comment: The option does not say anywhere "Format the Entire Drive". It says it will replace Windows for Ubuntu and delete all documents, photos, etc..

Comment: @LuisAlvarado etc there includes "**and** any other files".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On installation whenever the installer finds another OS on the drive we can choose to install "Alongside" in dual- or multi-boot, or we can choose to "Replace..." an existing OS with Ubuntu.

#### "Replace" in the case of one harddisk

This will repartition the enire **drive** with standard partitions for Ubuntu. All other partitions including Windows (e.g. `C:`), and all data partitions (e.g. `D:`, `E:`,...) on that drive will be deleted and **overwritten**.

This also is why we have so many questions from unfortunate people who erroneously assumed that only a single partition will be used.

#### "Replace" in the case of several harddisks

This is different on a system having more than one physical drive. The installer then lets us choose which drive to use. Still, the drive chosen will be deleted and repartitioned as a whole.

[image]
<sup>Installer of 14.04. in Virtual Box</sup>

#### "Something else" in the case we need to keep partitions

In case we need to preserve partitions on installation we should therefore choose to "Do something else" to be able to manually edit the partition layout. We then also have to make sure to **not format** those partitions we still need.

#### Too late - I only read this after I had removed all my data

In this case not all is lost. It is recommended to **stop using this drive** to be able to run data recovery tools as shown here:

- [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu/286206#286206)

Comment: Hi @Takkat, on Case one Hard Drive, are you talking about the option for "Replacing Windows for Ubuntu". If so can you clarify this, since this is more oriented towards new users with no experience yet about the installer.

Comment: Thanks Luis - edited for clarity - the intended audience also made me post a screenshot btw ;)